# Xamarin.Android - Get Call to Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory to show "My Files" view on device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on a file explorer feature in my app.The user clicks on a button and then can browse for files on the device's storage.I'm currently able to display the files on the sd card on a listview without any issues.I first check whether the call to `Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory` is a valid path.If it is,then i set the selected file(to be displayed) to the devices's sd card.That's when it's contents are populated on a list view.However,i want something more familiar to the users though.

Normally when you click on "My Files" on an android device,it shows you other components of the external storage other than the sd card.This is what i would like to achieve.I'd like to open the 'My Files' manager on any android device and select on either a file or folder and return the path  of the selected item.

Is there a known path to the android's file manager i.e 'My Files'?Here is a portion of the code that does that.

```
public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

            bool externalStorageState = isExternalStorageWritable ();
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (initialDirectory) && IsValidFile (initialDirectory)) {
            selectedFile = new File (initialDirectory);
        } else {

if (externalStorageState) {

                selectedFile = Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory;

            } else {

                Toast.MakeText (Activity, "External storage not available " , ToastLength.Long).Show ();

            }

        }

        return view;
    }

/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
    public bool isExternalStorageWritable() {
        string state = Environment.ExternalStorageState;
        if (Environment.MediaMounted.Equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Here is the My Files screen shots.

**After clicking on My Files.This is what i want to implement**
[image]

Comment: Still it's no clear what do you want to achive. What elements/files/folder do you want to have in your application?

Comment: There is a browse button in my activity.Currently when the user clicks on it,they see the third image above-the contents of the sd card because that is how i have set it for now.The initial path to be displayed is determined by what kind of storage exists on the device as some do not have an sd card.So in the code above,i check if that path is null or empty or invalid.If it's a valid path,its contents are displayed.If it's not valid,then we display the contents of Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.That's good,however,i would like the initial directory displayed to be the My Files(2nd image)

Comment: @Arttur Shamstudinov in a nutshell,i want to open 'my files' on any android device and be able to select a folder or file without opening to read it.Just selecting  it and returning the path of the selected file/folder

Comment: I think "My Files' is a custom application and there is no way to get exactly the same list of items. The only way to achieve your goal is to reproduce this interface manually.

Comment: Okay @ArturShamsutdinov Thank you for your feedback.I'll see what to do